# Abstract class inheritance with @Component (NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException)

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I am trying to create a structure with inheritance for my `@Component` classes in order to reuse some common code. But I am getting a runtime error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.myproject.MainComponent] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: A,B
```

So, I have created 3 classes as follows:

```
public abstract class MainComponent {
    ...
    void myMethodToOverride();
    void myCommonMethod() {
        // Some common code for A and B
    }
    ...
}

@Component
public class A extends MainComponent {
    ...
    @Override
    void myMethodToOverride() {
        // Some specific code of A class
    }
    ...
}


@Component
public class B extends MainComponent {
    ...
    @Override
    void myMethodToOverride() {
        // Some specific code of B class
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to this kind of inheritance with `@Component` of Spring (I am using 4.2.4 version)?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to `@Autowire` a `MainComponent` which is ambiguous because both `A` and `B` are suitable for the injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arnaud already mentioned you have an @Autowire with MainComponent.

To work around this you can use @Qualifier like descirbed here:

https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier